# Zero divisor in $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be commutative ring with no (nonzero) nilpotents. If $f(x) = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ is a zero divisor in $R[x]$, how do I show there's an element $b \ne 0$ in $R$ such that $ba_0=ba_1=\cdots=ba_n=0$?

Comment: The condition $R$ reduced is superfluous.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It is  true over any commutative ring, and is sometimes called McCoy's theorem. Below is a proof sketch
from my sci.math post on May 4, 2004:

**Theorem** $\ $ Let $ \,F \in R[X]$ be a polynomial over a commutative ring $ \,R.\,$
If $ \,F\,$ is a zero-divisor then $ \,rF = 0\,$ for some nonzero $ \,r \in R.$

**Proof** $\ $  Suppose not. Choose $ \,G \ne 0\,$ of min degree with $ \,FG = 0.\,$

Write $ \,F =\, a +\,\cdots\,+ f\ X^k +\,\cdots\,+ c\ X^m\ $

and $ \ \ \ \ G = b +\,\cdots\,+ g\ X^n,\,$ where $ \,g \ne 0,\,$ and $ \,f\,$ is the highest deg coef of $ \,F\,$ with $ \,fG \ne 0\,$ (note that such an $ \,f\,$ exists else $ \,Fg = 0\,$ contra supposition).

Then $ \,FG = (a +\,\cdots\,+ f\ X^k)\ (b +\,\cdots\,+ g\ X^n) = 0.$

Thus $\ \,fg = 0\ $ so $\: \deg(fG) < n\,$ and $ \, FfG = 0,\,$ contra minimality of $ \,G.\ \ $ **QED**

Alternatively it follows by Gauss's Lemma
(Dedekind-Mertens form) or related results.

Comment: Why does this imply that F(fG)=0? I understand that FG = 0 but why does this say something about the effect of F on the polynomial fG with deg(fG) < deg(G)?

Comment: $F(fG)=0$ follows from $FG=0$. The discussion before was needed in order to ensure that $\deg(fG)<\deg(G)$.

Comment: Bill, what an elegant proof! Thanks for sharing this lovely argument.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Hello! If we consider the field $Z_7$ and the polynomial $f=X^6-1$, clearly $f$ is nonzero and non-constant. For the polynomial $g=X$, we have: $fg=0$, by Fermat's Little Theorem. There is no $c\in Z_7,$ c different from 0 such that $cf=0$.

Comment: @user95553 While $\,fg =X^7 - X = 0\,$ as a polynomial *function* on $\,\Bbb Z_7,\,$ it is not true that $\,X^7-X = 0\,$ as  *formal* polynomials $\in \Bbb Z_7[X].\,$ Formal vs. functional polynomials is discussed in many prior answers, e.g. [this one.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/98365/242)

Comment: Why do we need the fact that $R$ is commutative ? Where do you use it ?

Comment: @user386627 The noncommutative case is more complicated, e.g. there are rings that are right McCoy but not left McCoy. You can find literature by searching with keywords: right/left McCoy, Armendariz, semicommutative, reversible, etc.

Comment: Ok, but where do you use the fact that $R$ is commutative in your proof ?

Comment: @user386627 e.g. $\,Fg = 0\ (\Rightarrow\, gF = 0),\,$ and $\,F(fG) = f(FG)= 0\ \ $

Comment: What an elegant argument. I really love your posts Bill. I hope you never leave MSE.

Comment: @BillDubuque, do you see a constructive argument (without Dedekind-Mertens)?

Answer (score 32):

Assume that $gf=0$ for some $g\in R[X]$ and let $c$ be the leading coefficient of $g$. Then $ca_n=0$. Therefore $cf$ is either $0$ (in which case $c$ is your $b$), or $cf$ has degree less than $n$ with $g(cf)=0$. Proceed by induction on $n$. In the end you find that some power of $c$ kills every $a_i$, and $c$ was not nilpotent ...

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, Bill Dubuque's argument is not really about polynomial rings. Here is a generalization.

> Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring. Let $f \in A$ be a zero divisor. Then there is some $0 \neq a \in A$ homogeneous such that $a f = 0$.

*Proof.* Choose some $0 \neq g \in A$ of minimal total degree with $fg=0$. Let $f=f_0+f_1+\cdots$ and $g=g_0+g_1+\cdots+g_d$ be the homogeneous decompositions with $g_d \neq 0$. If $f g_d = 0$, we are done. Otherwise, we have $f_i g_d \neq 0$ for some $i$, and hence $f_i g \neq 0$. Choose $i$ maximal with $f_i g \neq 0$. Then $0=fg=(f_0+\cdots+f_i)g=(f_0+\cdots+f_i)(g_0+\cdots+g_d)$ implies $f_i g_d = 0$. Then $f_i g$ has smaller degree than $g$, but still satisfies $f(f_i g)=0$ and $f_i g \neq 0$, a contradiction. $\square$

This may be applied to $A=R[x]$ with the usual grading. Hence, any zero divisor in $R[x]$ is killed by some element of the form $r x^n$ ($r \in R \setminus \{0\}$) and then also by $r$.

Comment: why is degree of $f_ig$ smaller than degree of $g$ (in graded ring)?

Comment: I've asked about the correctness of this proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1877149/178578)

Comment: @Jay The above proof can be easily fixed if one considers $g$ as having the minimal number of non-zero homogeneous components among the polynomials with the property $fg=0$. (As you can notice, the answerer wanted to mimic the proof given for polynomials in the accepted answer, and this is an easy task.)

Comment: @user26857: Yeah that makes sense. That's a neat trick, looking at the number of homogeneous components instead of the degree. Good to know this proof can be fixed!

Comment: Bill Dubuque is temporarily "Number $1$", in case someone does not know. See his answer above.

Comment: @Dietrich My username was "Number" then ( "1" was appended by SE in an unfounded descent!)

Answer (score 6):

This is the case of *Armendariz Rings*, which I studied in last summer briefly. It is an interesting topic.

> A ring $R$ is called *Armendariz* if whenever $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_ix^i, g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_jx^j \in R[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x)=0$,  then $a_ib_j=0\ \forall\ i,j$.

In his paper "A NOTE ON EXTENSIONS OF BAER AND P. P. -RINGS" in 1973, Armendariz proved that ***Reduced rings are Armendariz*** which is a nice generalization of your result.

**Proof-** Let $fg=0$ and assuming $m=n$ is sufficient. We then have $$a_0b_0=0,\\ a_1b_0+a_0b_1=0 ,\\ \vdots \\a_nb_0+\dots +a_0b_n=0$$

Since $R$ is reduced, $a_0b_0=0\implies (b_0a_0)^2=b_0(a_0b_0)a_0=0 \implies b_0a_0=0$.
Now left multiplying $a_1b_0+b_1a_0=0$ by $b_0$ we get $b_0a_1b_0=-b_0a_0b_1=0 \implies (a_1b_0)^2=a_1(b_0a_1b_0)=0 \implies a_1b_0=0$.
Similarly we get $a_ib_0=0\ \forall\ 1\leq i \leq n$.

Now original equations reduces to
$$a_0b_1=0\\ a_1b_1+a_0b_2=0\\ \vdots\\ a_{n-1}b_1+\dots +a_0b_n=0$$ and then by same process first we will get that $a_0b_1=0$ and then multiplying on left of $a_1b_1+a_0b_2=0$ by $b_1$ we get $a_1b_1=0$, and so on we will get, $a_ib_1=0\ \forall\ 1\le i \le n$.

Similarly, Repeating it we get $a_ib_j=0\ \forall\ 1 \leq i,j \leq n$. $\hspace{5.5cm}\blacksquare$

Some other examples of Armendariz Rings are:

- $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}\ \forall\ n$.
- All domains and fields (which are reduced).
- If A and B are Armendariz , then $A(+)B$ in which multiplication is  defined by $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',ab'+a'b)$ is Armendariz.
- Direct Product of Armendariz rings.

Comment: Are you assuming that $B$ is an $A$-algebra?

Answer (score 3):

Let f be a polynomial in the commutative ring R. Suppose fg is 0 where g is nonzero. Adjoining the coefficients of f and g to the prime subring we can assume the ring is Noetherian via the Hilbert Basis Theorem. Take a reduced primary decomposition of 0 in R. Extending each primary ideal to R[X] gives a primary decomposition for 0 in the polynomial ring. So f being a zerodivisor is contained in some P[X] where P is an associated prime of 0 in R. But P is killed by some nonzero c of R, so c kills f.