# Zero divisor polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)\in R[x]$ be a zero divisor. How to prove that there is an element $0\neq a\in R$ such that $af(x) = 0$?

If $R$ has no nilpotent elements, it is easy. What about the general case? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know it is true as N.Jacobson has noted in his book: Basi Algebra, Vol I.

Comment: I have tracked down Bill's answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/83171/11763 (Also, $R$ is commutative in your question right? If so, you should state so.)

Comment: Thanks very much. Please close this question.