# Proving that $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(px-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $p$ be prime, and $D=\{1,p,p^2,p^3,\dots\}$. The ring $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as the set of fractions $\{\frac{n}{d}:n\in\mathbb{Z},d\in D\}$. How would I show that the ring $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(px-1)$? I know by the first isomorphism theorem that the ideal $(px-1)$ is the kernel of a homomorphism $\varphi :\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$.

My issue is that I'm not sure how to actually construct this homomorphism. Any thoughts?

Comment: Construct homomorphisms in the two directions and check that they are mutually inverse. This is easier than computing the kernel.

Comment: Do you mean take some $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and check that $\varphi(p)=r$ and then check that $\varphi^{-1}(r)=p$? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: No, define ring homomorphisms $f:D^{-1}Z\to Z[x]/(px-1)$ and $g:Z[x]/(px-1)\to D^{-1}Z$ in some reasonable way, and then check that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are identity maps.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give it a go. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: There have been quite a few posts on this topic, for instance: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/localisation-is-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767765/localisation-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145685/showing-that-rx-xf-1-cong-r1-f?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839555/s-1a-cong-ax-1-ax?rq=1). Do any of these help?

Comment: Very much so. Thank you. @Quasicoherent

Comment: Okay, great. Unless you object, I'm going to vote to close this as a duplicate.