# Primeness of irreducible elements in R[X] for R a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I don't understand the last passage in [this](http://ericmalm.net/ac/projects/math210b-w08/math210b-poly-ring-ufd.pdf) proof.

We assume that $P(X)\in R[X]$ is irreducible and want to show that it is prime. So we must prove that $P(X)\mid F(X)G(X)$ implies either $P(X)\mid F(X)$ or $P(X)\mid G(X)$ (in $R[X]$). So we assume that $P(X)\mid F(X)G(X)$, i.e., there is a $Q(X)\in R[X]$ such that $P(X)Q(X)=F(X)G(X)$ in $R[X]$ (and consequently in $K[X]$). How the Gauss lemma implies that either $P(X)\mid F(X)$ or $P(X)\mid G(X)$ in $K[X]$?

Comment: Since $P(X)\mid F(X)G(X)$ in $R[X]$ then $P(X)\mid F(X)G(X)$ in $K[X]$. By Gauss' Lemma $P(X)$ is irreducible in $K[X]$, hence prime. (Recall that $K[X]$ is a UFD.) Then $P(X)\mid F(X)$ or $P(X)\mid G(X)$ in $K[X]$.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/829895/242) for how to prove a more general *polynomial primality criterion*.