# Irreducible polynomial over integers : sufficient conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Why is $9x^{2}-3$ reducible over integers? I am not able to understand what are the necessary and sufficient condition for the irreducibility of a polynomial.

Comment: Well $9x^2 - 3 = 3(3x^2 -1)$ : is $3$ a unit in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ ?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there are different definitions of irreducibility. The confusion comes mainly from the context.

Some literature has defined irreducible polynomials (over some ring, in this case, $\mathbb{Z}$) as the polynomials that cannot be factored into the product of two NON-CONSTANT polynomials. In this way $9x^2-3$ is irreducible.

However if we consider the irreducibility in the domain $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the definition of irreducibility is that when $f$ is factored into $g\dot\ h$, either $g$ or $h$ is a unit (has an inverse). In this way, $3$ is definitely not a unit, so $9x^2-3$ is not irreducible.

I have encountered both definitions, and they have also brought confusion. Hope my explanation helps.

Comment: There are no *different* definitions of irreducibility. There are only wrong interpretations of the definition of an irreducible element in an integral domain when use it for polynomials.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks, but I really encountered both definitions in Chinese translations of math books, as well as standard Chinese math textbooks. So maybe it's a translation error.

Comment: I didn't say that you invented such things. I'm sure these *different* definitions there exist. The point is that those authors could be wrong. (Please read egreg's answer to see how natural the things are in fact.)

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much! Egreg's answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

> **Definition.** Let $R$ be an integral domain. An element $a\in R$, $a\ne0$ and not a unit, is *reducible* if (and only if) there exist non units $b,c\in R$ such that $a=bc$. An element $a\in R$, $a\ne0$ and not a unit, is *irreducible* if and only if it is not reducible.

Equivalently, $a$ ($a\ne0$ and not a unit) is irreducible if and only if, for every $x,y\in R$, if $a=bc$ then either $b$ is a unit or $c$ is a unit.

In your case
$$
9x^2-3=3(3x^2-1)
$$
is a factorization where neither factor is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

On the other hand, the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ because it has no roots (which is a sufficient condition for polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$ *over a field*).

What’s a necessary and sufficient condition for a nonzero polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to be irreducible?

First, define the *content* $c_f$ of $f(x)$ to be the positive greatest common divisor of its coefficients. Any nonzero polynomial can be written as
$$
f(x)=c_f \hat{f}(x)
$$
where the content of $\hat{f}(x)$ is $1$ (such a polynomial is called *primitive*).

If the polynomial is constant (and not $\pm1$), then it is irreducible if and only if $c_f$ is prime.

Assume $f$ is not constant. Then, in order to be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, it is necessary that $c_f=1$ and that $\hat{f}(x)$ is irreducible.

Now (a consequence of) [Gauss’ lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) tells you that a primitive polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Readers may find of interest [this related result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829895/242) over a domain $\,\rm D\,$ with quotient field $\,\rm K$ $$\rm f\,\ is\ prime\ in\ D[x]\iff  f\,\ is\ prime (= irreducible)\ in\ K[x]\ and\,\ f\,\ is\ superprimitive $$

$$\rm where\,\ f\,\ is\ {\bf superprimitive}\ in\ D[x]\,\ :=\,\  d\,|\,cf\, \Rightarrow\, d\,|\,c\,\ \ for\ all\,\ c,d\in D^*$$