# Find not irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

[image]

Actually I tried solving it.

A) By Eisenstein's Criteria its is irreducible.

B) and C) These polynomials don't have any zero in $\mathbb Z$ hence are also irreducible.

D) I have doubt in this tried it like ...
Let $$x=y+1$$ then equation becomes $$y^4 + 5y^3+10y^2+10y+5.$$

By Eisenstein's Criterion this is also irreducible.

But its not possible, one of them is not irreducible!!
Can someone help me?

Comment: Unrelated: I know only one Eisenstein criterion. Do you know another one?

Answer (score 5):

$2x^3+6x+12 =2(x^3+3x+6)$

Note that $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb Z [x]$.

The criterion you cited (that having no roots implies irreducibility for polynomials of degree $\leq 3$) works only over fields.

Comment: Its over Z not Z[x]

Comment: @user458361 irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ is the same thing as being an irreducible element in the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[x]$

Comment: @user458361 For elaboration on the prior comment see [this recent question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2329482/242)

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Thanks a lot bro!!