# When is the ideal generated by linear polynomial prime?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over an integral domain $R$. When is the ideal $(r_1x_1+\ldots+r_nx_n)$ for some $r_1,\ldots,r_n \in R$ prime?

Comment: If $D$ is a domain [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829895/242) $\, f\,$ is prime in $\,D[x] \iff\!\underbrace{f\,\ \rm is\ prime\  in\  K[x]}_{\large\iff  f\rm\ is\ irreducible\quad }\!$ and $\,f\,$ is superprimitive. $\ \ $

Comment: Thanks. We can apply induction by number of variables. But, is there a condition in terms of $r_1,\ldots,r_n$?