# Prime $p\in R$ remains prime in $R[x]$ (Gauss's Lemma)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain , $p \in R$ be a prime element , then is $p$ also a prime element in $R[x]$ ?

I know it is true if $R$ is a UFD , because then the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a UFD and showing $p$ is prime is equivalent to showing it is irreducible .

But what of $R$ is not a UFD ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use the fact that $R[x]/(p) = (R/p)[x]$. Then $R/p$ is an integral domain because $p$ is prime so the polynomial ring $(R/p)[x]$ [is as well](http://planetmath.org/polynomialringoverintegraldomain). And by definition $\mathfrak{p}$ an ideal of a ring $S$ [is prime iff](http://planetmath.org/primeideal) $S/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's instructive to give a *direct* proof of $\,p\nmid A,B\,\Rightarrow\,p\nmid AB.\,$ Since $\,p\nmid A,B\,$ when reduced mod $p$ both have lead coefs $\,\color{#0a0}{a,b\not\equiv 0}\,$ so $AB\,$ has lead coef $\,\color{#c00}{ab\not\equiv 0}\,$ (by $\,p\,$ prime), hence $AB\not\equiv 0,\,$ i.e.

$\ \ \ \ \qquad{\rm mod}\ p\!: \ \ \ \begin{eqnarray}
&&\ 0\ \not\equiv\ A\ \equiv\, \color{#0a0}a\, x^j\! + \:\cdots,\quad\ \ \:\! \color{#0a0}{a\not\equiv 0}\\  
&&\ 0\ \not\equiv\ B\ \equiv\, \color{#0a0}b\, x^k\! + \:\cdots,\quad\ \ \, \color{#0a0}{b\not\equiv 0}\\ 
\Rightarrow\,\ &&0 \not\equiv AB \equiv \color{#c00}{ab}\ x^{j+k}\! + \:\cdots,\, \color{#c00}{ab\not\equiv 0}\end{eqnarray}$

i.e. primes $\,p\in R\,$ remain prime in $\,R[x]\,$  because  $\,\color{#0a0}{p\nmid a,b}\,\Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{p\nmid ab}\,$  [*prime divisor property*] always *persists* when $\rm\color{#c00}{multiplying}$ $\rm\color{#0a0}{lead\ coef's}$. This is one form of [Gauss's Lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29)

This is precisely an *elementwise* view of the *structural* sketched by Adam's  (it's simply the proof of $\,D$ domain $\Rightarrow D[x]\,$ domain, in the special case that $\,D \cong R/p \cong R\bmod p,\,$ for $\,p\,$ prime).

**Beware** $ $ The "primitive" form of Gauss's Lemma depends crucially on $R$ being UFD. For if $R$ has an atom (irreducible) $\,p\,$ that is not  prime then there exists $a,b\,$  such that $\,p\mid ab,\  p\nmid a,\ p\nmid b\,$ so $\,f= px+a,\,g = px+b\,$ are primitive but $\,p\mid fg\,$ so $\,fg\,$ is not primitive, so Gauss's Lemma fails. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2974861/242) for more.

Comment: The above proof immediately extends from a principal prime ideal $(p)$  to any prime ideal $P$ in a commutative ring $R$ -  just replace $\,p\mid a\,$ by $\,a\in P\,$ etc. It is an elementwise form of the [standard structural proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170643/prove-that-if-i-is-a-prime-ideal-of-r-then-ix-is-a-prime-ideal-of-rx) that reduces to the trivial domain case by [factoring out $P[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3716/242).