# General questions about Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm learning about polynomial rings in my class. My instructor and book are both spectacularly unhelpful and didn't even bother to define most of the terms in my homework. So I have some general questions. I have covered and understand everything through basic ring theory. This will be a relatively long post and any help will be appreciated.

1) I know what an integral domain is. In order for a polynomial ring to be an integral domain is it true that say, $$f(x), g(x) \in F[x]:\ f(x) + g(x) = g(x) + f(x),\ f(x)g(x) = g(x)f(x),\ \exists 1_F \in F,\ f(x)g(x) \implies f(x)=0 \text{ or } g(x) = 0\ ?$$

2) I know what units of a ring are. How would I find them for a polynomial ring? Say $\Bbb Q[x],\ \Bbb Z[x],\ \Bbb Z_5[x]$. (These are the "examples" from my book where it leaves them to the reader to solve.)

3) Irreducibility. My book and instructor both didn't even bother to define this. From trolling google, it seems to me that if $f(x) \in F[x]$ can be written as say $f(x) = p(x)q(x)$ where the degrees of $p(x),q(x) \neq 0$, then it is reducible. So if someone could define this for me correctly that would help.

4) Zeros. My book didn't define this either. It just went on to ask questions about it. When I have to find the zeros of say $f(x) = x^3 + 3x + 5$ in $\Bbb Z_7$, does this mean I set $f(x) = 0 $ and find $x$ in $\Bbb Z_7$?

5) Zero Divisors. I know that if $(R,+,∘)$ is a ring, then $x$ is a zero divisor if $∃y∈R^∗:x∘y=0_R$. So when the "examples" my book gives asks the reader to find them for $\Bbb Z_4[x]$ and $\Bbb Z_5[x]$. I'm guessing I need to find $f(x),g(x)∈R[x]^∗:f(x)g(x)=0_{R_[x]}$. But how do I do that generally? There could be infinitely many polynomials that satisfy that.

I apologize for the lengthiness and broadness of these questions. I am legitimately trying to understand the concept of Polynomial Rings, but my instructor and the book she has chosen have made it nearly impossible. I would appreciate any references to online material that would explain the concepts better as well. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome to ask for definitions of terms, but it would help your Readers if you provide some context.  What book is it that fails to define *irreducibility* and other terms for polynomial rings?  This would give some guide as to what studies you have completed.

Comment: My university has an in-house text book that we use. I would link you all to a pdf or an online resource but we don't really have one. Again. I apologize. I know my questions might seem difficult.

Comment: I would have to start scanning pages and they are pretty spaced out.

Comment: You are a bit unfair to your book (and may be to your instructor), don't you think ? It cannot be "nearly impossible" to find out these things. Since you are online, you can find all of what you want (without scanning).

Comment: No, I don't want you to start scanning pages.  It would suffice to give the title and author, however "in-house" this textbook might be.  Certainly university name would help as well.

Comment: An Introduction to Abstract Algebra, by Ronald Solomon (in-house notes).
It is some odd, two part book. I took that gentleman's Real Analysis class last year. We started out with about 30 students and finished with 7 if that gives you any idea.

Comment: A good online resource for definitions and some worked exercises is [Abstract Algebra Online](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/) based on books by Beachy and Blair.

Answer (score 2):

Much of this would be covered in "basic ring theory".  Let's say that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity (although more general settings can be accommodated, it seems like a good place to start).

As you studied "polynomials" in calculus you were asked to consider them as *functions* of one or more variables.  In abstract algebra there is more of an emphasis on polynomials as elements of a symbolic ring *extension*.

The *univariate* (single variable) case is to define a ring $R[X]$, where we will often refer to the symbol $X$ not as a variable (which is useful if polynomials are considered as functions) but as an *indeterminate*, meaning that it has no specified value in connection with the base ring of coefficients $R$.  In other words $X$ is a purely symbolic value, and we define polynomials in this single indeterminate as a finite sum of natural powers of $X$ (including $1\in R$ as the special case $X^0$) times coefficients from $R$.

For example a polynomial $f(X)\in R[X]$ of *degree* $n$ has the form:

$$ f(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n r_k X^k \; \text{ where } \; r_k\in R \; \text{ for } k=0,\ldots,n $$

So $X^2 + 2X + 1$ is polynomial from the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, or from any polynomial ring $R[X]$ in which the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are considered to be a subring of $R$.

Addition and multiplication of polynomials is done as you learned in secondary education, using distributivity and collection of "like terms".

(1) A polynomial ring is an integral domain in the same sense as any commutative ring with unity is an integral domain, namely that a product of two elements is zero only if one or the other of the two elements is zero.  (I phrase it this way because you say you are already familiar with the meaning of *integral domain*.)

An interesting exercise is to prove that $R[X]$ is an integral domain if and only if $R$ is an integral domain.  Some familiarity with induction and the *degree* of a polynomial is needed to prove this.

(2) The notion of a *unit* for polynomial rings is again the same as for all commutative rings with unity.  In particular a *unit* is an element that has a multiplicative inverse.

Another interesting exercise is to prove that if $R$ is an integral domain, then $R[X]$ has essentially the same units as $R$, in the sense that a unit of $R[X]$ is a "constant" polynomial $C_0 \in R$ that is already invertible in $R$.

(3) An irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in R[X]$ is an element that has factors:

$$ f(X) = g(X)h(x) $$

only of the form where $g(X)$ or $h(X)$ is a unit.  This is not quite the idea you described, because we don't require merely that $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ cannot both have smaller degrees than $f(X)$.  For example, $f(X) = 2X + 4$ is *not* irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ because $f(X) = 2\cdot(X+2)$ is a way to factor into nonunits over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.  On the other hand, if your base ring were $R = \mathbb{Q}$, the rational numbers rather than the integers, we would consider $2$ to be a unit, and thus $f(X) = 2X+4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

(4) Zeros of a polynomial are the same as *roots* of a polynomial, and for this concept we switch back to thinking of polynomials as *functions*.  In other words, $r\in R$ is a *root* (zero) of polynomial $f(X)$ if and only if assigning the value $X=r$ results in polynomial evaluation to zero, $f(r) = 0$.  From an abstract algebra point of view, this "polynomial evaluation" at $X=r$ amounts to a ring homomorphism from $R[X]$ into $R$.  Different values of $r\in R$ will give different ring homomorphisms.

Often a ring may lack the roots (zeros) for a polynomial that we would like to have.  For example $f(X) = X^2 + 1$ has no roots over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, or even over the rational or real polynomials.  But it will have two distinct roots if we extend coefficients to the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}[X]$.  Much of the further steps in abstract ring theory will examine the process of constructing ring extensions that produce roots.

(5)  Zero divisors in polynomial rings have again the same definition as for commutative rings with unity in general.  That is, if a (nonzero) element can be multiplied by another nonzero element to give a product zero, then we can say that element is a zero divisor.  Notice that an integral domain is simply a commutative ring with unity that *has no zero divisors*.

Note that typically an author excludes zero itself from consideration as a *zero divisor*, but perhaps it makes sense to always qualify the meaning by saying an integral domain has no zero divisors other than zero.

We can thus restate an earlier proposed exercise as proving $R[X]$ has no zero divisors if and only if $R$ has no zero divisors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I'm pretty sure that's definition is correct. Basically, this means that the ring has commutative addition, commutative multiplication, and there's no way you can multiply two non-zero polynomials and get $0$.
2. Any polynomial that has an $x$ term in it can not be a unit. There is no way you can multiply something with an $x$ in it and then get $1$. It just doesn't make sense. There's no way to eliminate the $x$ through multiplication. Therefore, to find the units of the polynomial ring, just find the units of the original ring. For example, the units of $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ is $\Bbb{Q}-\{0\}$ because all rational numbers (except $0$) are units and the units of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ is $\{-1, 1\}$.
3. I'm also pretty sure that definition is also correct. Basically, this means that if $f(x)$ is irreducible, then the only thing that can be factored out of it is a unit. It is not factorable into smaller 
   polynomials.
4. Yes, your idea of the zeroes of polynomial is correct. With a finite ring like $\Bbb{Z}_7$, you can simply guess and check from $0$ to $6$ and see which ones come out to $0$.

Number 5 is kind of harder to explain, in my opinion, so I'm going to let someone else do that or I will come back to this later and notify you once I have added them to this answer. This [theorem on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83121/zero-divisor-in-rx/83171#83171) might help you understand how to find zero divisors. Please ask if you have any confusion about anything I said here!