# How to show $\langle 7\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I know that since $\Bbb Z$ is commutative and unital $\langle 7\rangle$ is just the polynomials whose coefficients are all in $7\Bbb Z$.

I know that since $\Bbb Z[x]$ is commutative that in order to show $\langle 7\rangle$ is a prime ideal show:
$ab \in \langle 7\rangle$ implies $a \in \langle 7\rangle$ or $b \in \langle 7\rangle$ for all a,b in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

I have calculated what form ab is using Cauchy product. I now have stated each coefficient is in $7\Bbb Z$ but Im finding it hard to show how this requires either a or b lies in $\langle 7\rangle$

Comment: I suggest finding a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[X]$ to an integral domain whose kernel is $\left<7\right>$.

Comment: If you want to do things using the cauchy product a nice approach is as follows: show that if $a$ is not in $\langle 7 \rangle$, then $b$ must be in $\langle 7 \rangle$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $p$ is a prime ideal then $p[X]$ is a prime ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846511/if-p-is-a-prime-ideal-then-px-is-a-prime-ideal).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(7) = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(7)} [x]$

the latter is clearly an integral domain, therefore (7) is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.