# Let R be a commutative ring in which $a^2 = 0$ only if $a = 0$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been doing some practice problems for an upcoming intro level abstract algebra class and came across this problem (in Herstein 3rd edition, Ch 4.5 #26 & #28). I had some help from my professor with reasoning through the first part but am unsure if I got it or not.

i) Let $R$ be a commutative ring in which $a^2 = 0$ only if $a = 0$. Show that if
$q(x) \in R[x]$ is a zero-divisor in $R[x]$, then, if
$q(x) = a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0$
there is an element $b \neq 0$ in $R$ such that $ba_0 = ba_1 = ... = ba_n = 0$.

ii) Show that the element b must exist even if the condition "$a^2 = 0$ only if $a = 0$" does not hold

My figuring thus far:
Let $h(x) \in R[x]$ such that $h(x)q(x) = 0 = q(x)h(x)$ , where $h(x) = c_mx^m+c_{m-1}x^{m-1} + ... + c_1x+c_0$. We know that the product of these polynomials is zero, so we know that every coefficient of the product must be zero: $q(x)h(x) = a_nc_mx^{m+n} + (a_nc_{m-1} + a_{n-1}c_m)x^{n+m-1} + ... + a_0c_0 = 0 \rightarrow a_n$ and $c_m$ are zero divisors in $R$ (as we will have written $h(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that their leading coefficients are nonzero). We also know that $a_nc_{m-1} + a_{n-1}c_m = 0 \rightarrow c_m(a_nc_{m-1}+a_{n-1}c_m) = 0 \rightarrow 0 = (c_ma_n)c_{m-1} = -c_m^2a_{n-1}$. Following this line of reasoning it seems that $b= c_m^k$ for some appropriate k (I think k=n+1?).

Does this seem correct? In my mind this is an appropriate proof for i) and ii) but I suspect something more nuanced is going on in ii) that I'm missing. EDIT: I think in part two the issue is that I can't say $c_m^2a_{n-1} = 0$ because I haven't shown that $a_{n-1} \neq j^2$ for some $j \in R$, but I'm still not really sure.

Thanks for any and all input.

(Meta: First post. Was this appropriate? If not let me know how I can improve)

Comment: Your idea is basically correct: $b=c_m^{n+1}$ works. Can you see why $b \neq 0$? That's because $c_m \neq 0 \Rightarrow c_m^2 \neq 0 \Rightarrow c_m^4 \neq 0 \Rightarrow c_m^8 \neq 0$ and so on until you get a sufficiently large power of $2$. The problem is that this argument does not work in ii).

Comment: You could compare it with  [this highly voted post with several solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83121/29335) or [this blog with a complete solution](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/tag/mccoy-theorem/). As for "is it appropriate," it is technically OK since you're asking for some verification of your reasoning. One wonders though if you made any attempt to find solutions before posting, though. If you did, mention it, link them, tell us why the solutions don't help you. If you didn't... well, make it a habit to look before you ask.

Comment: Thanks, I just hadn't found these sources in looking for them (I didn't really know the terminology "nilpotents" or I would have tried looking for that). I'll try to be more careful.