# Prove that: $R[x]$ has a zero divisor $\Rightarrow$ $R$ has a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra

### The problem

I've been trying to solve the above problem. There seems to already be some work regarding zero divisors in polynomial rings [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83171/616935), but I'm not sure it is applicable to me, because it looks specifically for some $r \in R$ such that for a zero divisor $F \in R[x]$ holds $F \cdot r = 0$.

I, on the other hand, am looking to prove that if $R[x]$ has zero divisors, it implies $R$ has zero divisors.

### My ideas so far

I've thought of the following: 
Let $p(x), q(x) \in R[x], \quad p(x) \neq 0 \neq q(x), \quad p(x) \cdot q(x) = 0$.

Since the product of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is zero, it shouldn't matter which $x \in R$ you choose. The product should still be zero regardless. So, freely choosing a single $x \in R$, we should be able to reduce both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ to a value in $R$, with the equation still holding. As such, we'd have found our zero divisors in $R$.

Unfortunately, we have to watch out so that $x$ isn't a zero of either $p(x)$ or $q(x)$, or else we'd reduce one of them to $0$ and as such we wouldn't be finding a zero divisor. This leaves me stuck.

Obviously, for my approach I'd have to show that there is an $x \in R$, so that neither $p(x)$ nor $q(x)$ reduce to $0$.

Comment: Can you look at the leading coefficients ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed this answer up before the notation was changed so that the base ring is referred to as $R$ instead of $\Bbb K$.  So bear with me if you will . . .

It unnecessarily complicates things to look for $y \in \Bbb K$ with

$p(y) \ne 0 \ne q(y), \tag 1$

where

$p(x), q(x) \in \Bbb K[x]; \tag 2$

indeed, there is no *a priori* reason to suppose such a $y$ even exists; instead, it is easier, I'll warrant, to simply realize that the "$x$" in "$\Bbb K[x]$" does not represent an element of $\Bbb K$; rather, it is an *indeterminate* used to define, and allow the manipulation of, polynomials as abstract entities.

Bearing this in mind, we suppose that

$0 \ne p(x) \in \Bbb K[x] \tag 3$

is a zero divisor; then

$\exists 0 \ne q(x) \in \Bbb K[x] \tag 4$

with

$p(x)q(x) = 0; \tag 5$

now with

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg p} p_j x^j \tag 6$

and

$q(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg q} q_j x^j, \tag 7$

we have

$p_{\deg p} \ne 0 \ne q_{\deg q}, \tag 8$

since they are the leading coefficients of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, respectively; but

$0 = p(x)q(x) = \left (\displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg p} p_i x^i \right ) \left (\displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg q} q_j x^j \right )$
$=  \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\deg p + \deg q} \left ( \sum_{i = 0}^k p_{k - i}q_i \right )x^k$
$= p_{\deg p}q_{\deg q}x^{\deg p + \deg q} +\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\deg p + \deg q - 1} \left ( \sum_{i = 0}^k p_{k - i}q_i \right )x^k,\tag 9$

whence

$p_{\deg p}q_{\deg q} = 0; \tag{10}$

that is, $p_{\deg p}$ and $q_{\deg q}$ are zero-divisors in $\Bbb K$.

In closing, I think it is worthy of note that what we have directly proved here is but the contrapositive of the well-known but elementary result that $\Bbb K[x]$ is an integral domain if $\Bbb K$ is, the proof of which is also typically had *via* examining the 
leading coefficients of $p(x)$, $q(x)$, and $p(x)q(x)$.

Answer (score 6):

You want to show that if $R$ is a domain, $R[x]$ is a domain.

So, suppose that $R$ is a domain, then take $P,Q\in R[x]$.

Let $aX^n$ and $bX^m$ be the monomials of maximal degree in $P$ resp. $Q$, then the maximal degree monomial of $PQ$ is $abX^{n+m}$, of course if $ab\neq 0$. But as $R$ has no zero divisor, this is true.

So $R[x]$ is a domain.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful: when we write $R[x]$ for the ring of polynomials, $x$ is *not* an element of $R$. A polynomial $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ is zero, *by definition*, if and only if $a_0=a_1=\dots=a_n=0$.

You're confusing with “polynomial functions”, but the concepts of polynomial and polynomial function are to be kept distinct.

If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n\in R[x]$, then $f$ induces a polynomial function $\varphi_f\colon R\to R$ by $\varphi_f(r)=f(r)$. Note that it is very possible that for two distinct polynomials $f$ and $g$ it holds that $\varphi_f=\varphi_g$. It is the case when $R$ is a finite ring.

Suppose $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ is a zero divisor; in particular it is not the zero polynomial, so we can assume $a_n\ne0$. Then there exists a nonzero polynomial $g(x)=b_0+b_1x+\dots+b_mx^m$ and $b_m\ne0$ such that $f(x)g(x)=0$. Since the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$ in $f(x)g(x)$ is $a_nb_m$, we conclude that $R$ has zero divisors.