# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ an integral domain? If so, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to solve a larger problem about maximal and prime ideal, and knowing if $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an integral domain would really help me

Comment: Do you know the definition of an integral domain?

Comment: $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Z}[x], ab=0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$

Comment: Right.  Can you multiply two non-zero polynomials together to get $0$?

Comment: Ahhhhhhh cheers

Comment: As an exercise:  prove that, for an integral domain $R$, $R[x]$ is always an integral domain.  Useful lemma.

Answer (score 1):

There is something slightly stronger that is true due to McCoy that you might find interesting regarding zero-divisors in polynomial rings and the relation to the original ring.

Let $F\in R[X]$ be a polynomial over a commutative ring $R$. If $F$ is a zero-divisor then $rF=0$ for some nonzero $r\in R$.  The top answer here gives a sketch of the argument: [Zero divisor in $R[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83121/zero-divisor-in-rx)